# Rust binary and library can't find each other

Tags: rust

I have a static library (OS kernel in Rust), so I have a file tree:

- src/
- src/lib.rs

I added a binary so that I could actually run my kernel (the kernel functions are implemented in the library). This is a feature of a project, once enabled, it "enables" the additional `src/main.rs` file to compile and run the kernel as well as makes the project depend on the `bootloader` crate; if the feature is not enabled, the `src/main.rs` file isn't compiled, the `bootloader` crate isn't used for the project, and I call the `src/lib.rs` functions myself directly from an assembly file by linking the static library produces by rustc later myself:

```
[package]
name = "myos"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

# This is for the case of `src/bin/main.rs` which doesn't work as well.
#[[bin]]
#name = "main"
#required-features = ["bootloader"]

[dependencies.bootloader]
version = "0.10"
optional = true

[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"

[features]
default = ["bootloader"]
```

The problem is that the `main.rs` can't see the `lib.rs` no matter what I try:

**lib.rs**

```rust
#![no_std]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn main() -> i32 {
    0
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn kernel_early() {

}

pub fn myos_panic(info: &core::panic::PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

**main.rs**

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use myos::{kernel_early, main};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    kernel_early();
    main();

    loop {}
}

use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[panic_handler]
fn panic(info: &PanicInfo<'_>) -> ! {
    crate::myos_panic(info);
}
```

The crate's name of the project is `myos`. Here is what I've tried so far to use the `kernel_early` and `main` functions from the `lib.rs` module in the `main.rs`:

```rust
use myos::{kernel_early, main};
use crate::{kernel_early, main};
use super::{kernel_early, main};
```

Tried even playing with `mod lib; use lib::*`, of course, it only made things worse.

How do I make the binary actually work with my library? I made tons of cargo examples and I know how they work, it just seems it doesn't work with such a project structure where a binary and a library are all within one single crate. I also tried moving the `src/main.rs` to `src/bin/main.rs` but the effect was exactly the same.

The errors I have are:

```
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use myos::{kernel_early, main};
  |     ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `myos`

error[E0432]: unresolved imports `crate::kernel_early`, `crate::main`
 --> src/main.rs:4:13
  |
4 | use crate::{kernel_early, main};
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^ no `main` in the root
  |             |
  |             no `kernel_early` in the root

error[E0425]: cannot find function `myos_panic` in the crate root
  --> src/main.rs:18:12
   |
18 |     crate::myos_panic(info);
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in the crate root
```

P.S. The problem is not in the name mangling, as I also tried calling functions without it disabled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've specified `crate-type = ["staticlib"]` for your library, which produces, only, a library in the target's native static library format. You cannot use such a library as an ordinary Rust crate (`use myos::`), because that requires an `"rlib"` (or equivalently for the time being, `"lib"`) crate type.

I think it might work if you declare the functions in the library like they were C functions, i.e.

```rust
extern {
   fn main() -> i32;
   fn kernel_early();
}
```

and link to the compiled staticlib as you would to a C library. (I don't know how that actually works; I've only ever used `-sys` crates myself.)

However, if you want to do anything Rusty that can't be done through the C ABI (like generic functions), this won't help you. If I understand correctly, your binary is just for *testing* the library code. In that case, you can change your target configuration to

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["staticlib", "lib"]
```

and then Cargo will build *both* formats; the `lib` for your test binary and the `staticlib` for your bare metal bootloader.